# Apache C module how to send response to client

Tags: c, http, apache2, apache-modules

I have written an Apache module that handles receiving a file from a client. I now want to send a response back to the client. I want the response to contain a string representing the file path to the file sent to the module. Since I am new to writing Apache modules I am unsure as to whether there is a response struct of some sort I need to use or if everything I need is in the request_rec passed into my handler. I noticed that ap_rprintf sends data to the client. Should I just use that? And if so, how is it sent back to the client (i.e. how can my client extract the string from things sent back to it)?

Thanks!

Edit: 
I just stumbled across apr_socket_send() but I don't know if that works in this case. request_rec stores the connection, so could I create a socket to the client and send the data back that way?

Comment: Which manual are you reading? What have you tried? Where is your testcase? What went wrong with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you checked out the source code for [mod_example](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_example.html)?

Basically:

```
r->content_type = "text/html";
ap_send_http_header(r);
ap_rputs(DOCTYPE_HTML_3_2, r);
ap_rputs("<HTML>\n", r);
...
ap_rprintf(r, "Stuff that you want to send in the body");
...
```

Comment: How does ap_rprintf send the data back to the client? Is it appended to the response headers?

Comment: The second line above sends the response header. Then ap_rprintf is just like printf -- it just writes to the stream that is connected to the client.

Comment: OK. So when I write that data to the stream, my client should just be able to extract it from the connection it made?

Comment: Is it necessary to send the response header in order to use ap_rprintf?

Comment: Is your client something other than a web browser? In any case, yes, the client just sees the headers and everything else coming in on the same socket. You need to send a response header first if you want to speak HTTP.

Comment: The client isn't a web browser. So looking through examples it seems like ap_rprintf and ap_rputs actually put the data in the response headers. Is that accurate? Also thank you for your help. You're awesome

Comment: ap_rprintf and ap_rputs send stuff directly to the stream that is connected to the client. If your client does not need the HTTP headers, you can skip sending them. The `r` in the example code is a `request_rec` struct -- it contains a bunch of info. You give it to the ap_rp... functions so that they know what stream to write to.